# Bind a service property to a component property with proper change tracking

Tags: angular, angular2-services

Consider the utterly simple Angular 2 service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Category} from "../models/Category.model";

@Injectable()
export class CategoryService {
    activeCategory: Category|{} = {};
    constructor() {};
}
```

And then the component using this service:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {CategoryService} from "../shared/services/category.service";
import {Category} from "../shared/models/Category.model";

@Component({
    selector: 'my-selector',
    template: `
    {{categoryService.activeCategory.Name}}<br/>
    {{category.Name}}<br/>
`,
})
export class MySelectorComponent implements OnInit {
    category:Category|{} = {};

    constructor(public categoryService:CategoryService){};

    ngOnInit() {
        this.category = this.categoryService.activeCategory;
    };
}
```

Assume appropriately defined Category model and assume that another component somewhere sets the activeCategory on the service to a valid Category at some point.  Assume that the categoryservice is set as provider at an appropriately higher level.

When that happens, the first line in the template will correctly display the category Name, but the second line will not.  I've tried using getters and setters vs. raw access on the service; I've tried primitive types vs. objects vs. object properties; I can't believe that the first line is the appropriate paradigm for this type of access.  Can someone tell me the simplest way to bind a service property to a component property that will properly do change tracking in angular two?

**CLARIFICATION:** I know I could use observables that I create and push to for myself.  What I am asking is if there is any kind of already-baked into the framework way of doing this (that doesn't require me to write the huge amount of boilerplate for an observable) that just makes a variable track between the service and component.

Comment: Have your tried observables?

Comment: I know that I could create my own observable, but that is a LOT of boilerplate code for every single service property in both every service and in every component that uses that property of that service.  I'm hoping that's not the answer.

Comment: Indeed, I would definitely use Observables. It gives you tons of benefits and has become a common pattern for Angular 2 apps. With Observables you can use `ChangeDetectionStaregy.OnPush` which gives you a great performance boost as well. You could then use the `async` pipe in your view and directly bind the Observable there.

Comment: If you want I could post a solution using Observables if you don't know how to use them.

Comment: So I already have the ability to directly reference the service property in my template.  that's the first line in my template.  It's already there because the service is injected into my component.  Why in the world would I put all the code for an observable when I can just directly access the service property that is already there and in place anyway?"  All I really want is to essentially alias that already existent property from being this.categoryService.activeCategory to being this.activeCategory...

Comment: But its not really nice to directly call service methods or reference service properties in your template. Bad practice I would say.

Comment: You can always have a "holder" object that you never change or reassign. Just like how it used to be in angular1. In your example, it will be `holder: {activeCategory:Category|{}}= {activeCategory:undefined}`. That way, `categoryService.holder` should always be in sync across your app. Is this the kind of thing you are looking for?

Comment: I am still suggesting Observables here. Just embrace the way of reactive thinking. It's modern and the way how we develop angular apps in furture.

Comment: @Abdulrahman Yes, except that I tried that and it still does not allow me (in my component) to say this.activeCategory = categoryService.holder.activeCategory or even this.holder = categoryService.holder and have that stay in sync....

Comment: @Robert you can still do `get activeCategory(){return this.categoryService.holder.activeCategory;}`

Comment: alright per the answer below, I'm accepting that using a subject/behavior paradigm and manually subscribing in the component is the only way this works in ng2.  https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-build-angular-2-apps-using-observable-data-1 was of a lot of help in "getting" it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`Observable`s can be used without much boilerplate using `Behavior`s.

```
@Injectable() 
export class CategoryService {
  activeCategory:BehaviorSubject<{category:Category}> = new BehaviorSubject({category:null});
  // or just `Subject` depending on your requirements
}
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-selector',
  template: `
  {{(categoryService.activeCategory | async)?.Name}}<br/>
`,
})
export class MySelectorComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public categoryService:CategoryService){};
}
```

You also can just bind to properties of your service

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-selector',
  template: `
  {{categoryService?.activeCategory?.Name}}<br/>
`,
})
export class MySelectorComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public categoryService:CategoryService){};
}
```

Using the Elvis (or safe-navigation) operator you don't get an error if the `activeCategory` only gets a value later, for example when an async call completes.

Comment: still looks like accessing the categoryService directly in the template... I want to be able to say myLocalComponentProperty = service.property and have that track correctly.

Comment: Answer accepted but I'd recommend adding the required default and type for behavior subject.  e.g. `_activeCategory:BehaviorSubject<{category:Category}> = new BehaviorSubject({category:null});` or similar

Comment: Thanks! I don't use TS myself (only Dart) and are not familiar with the exact syntax for generic type parameters.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Does the last example work with something like an *ngFor? `*ngFor="let order of orderService.orders"` for example, gives me errors.

Comment: Sure. Perhaps the `orders` are fetched async and `null` when Angular renders the view. I don't know what your `.orders` is. `*ngFor="let order of orderService?.orders"` might work. If not it's probably better to create a new question with the code that demonstrates what you tried and full error message.

Answer (score 3):

You may try to substiture `ngOnInit()` with `ngDoCheck()`. I am not sure (actually I doubt) this is the right thing to do, in any case you can try.

This method is run at every change detection cycle (instead of the standard Angular algorithm I guess, and here is the potential issue) and therefore you shoud have the `category` property of `MySelectorComponent` up to date with the changes in the service.

Again need to be carefull of side effects (which are not clear to me).

Answer (score 0):

Not too big of a boilerplate chunk.
But what's going on here is that when the service is created or you make a call however your want to handle it. Your component will know about it through the subscription and then update your local variable to the new value. Allowing you to access it as this.activeCategory.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Category} from "../models/Category.model";
import {Subscription}   from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Injectable()
export class CategoryService {
    private _categoryObject = new Subject<any>();
    categoryObjectAnnounced$ = this._categoryObject;
    private _activeCategoryObject = new Subject<any>();
    activeCategoryObjectAnnounced$ = this._activeCategoryObject;
    activeCategory: Category|{} = {};
    constructor() {};
}


import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {CategoryService} from "../shared/services/category.service";
import {Category} from "../shared/models/Category.model";
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs/Subscription';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-selector',
    template: `
    {{activeCategory.Name}}<br/>
    {{category.Name}}<br/>
`,
})
export class MySelectorComponent implements OnInit {
    category:Category|{} = {};
    activeCategory:ActiveCategory|{} = {};
    activeCategorySubscription : Subscription;
    categorySubscription : Subscription;
    constructor(public categoryService:CategoryService){
          this.categorySubscription= this.categoryService.categoryObjectAnnounced$.subscribe((category) => {
             this.category= category;
          });

          this.activeCategorySubscription= this.categoryService.activeCategoryObjectAnnounced$.subscribe((active) => {
             this.activeCategory= active;
          });
    };
    ngOnInit() {

    };
}
```