# Get and update a string through a service in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I'm trying to better understand services by means of a very simple application which gets and updates the value of string within a service and displays it in a component.

Here's the service:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
  dataString: string;

  insertData(data) {
    this.dataString = data
  }
}
```

Here's the main 'app' component:

```
import {Component}      from 'angular2/core';
import {OtherComponent} from './other';
import {SharedService}  from'./shared.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [SharedService],
  directives: [OtherComponent],
  template: `
    <input type="text" #someValue>
    <button (click)="setSharedValue(someValue.value)">Change value in shared service</button>
    <br><br>
    <other></other>
  `
})
export class AppComponent { 
  constructor(private _sharedService: SharedService){}

  setSharedValue(value){
    this._sharedService.insertData(value);
  }

}
```

...and here's the 'other' component:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {SharedService} from './shared.service';

@Component({
  selector : "other",
  template : `
    I'm the other component. The shared data is: 
    <p>{{data}}</p>
  `,
})
export class OtherComponent implements OnInit{
  data: string;
  constructor(private _sharedService: SharedService){}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = this._sharedService.dataString;
  }
}
```

[Here's a plunkr.](https://plnkr.co/edit/wdwQdY8JI4qVBtQk82Ro?p=preview)

When text is added to the input and the button is clicked I want to display the value entered in the 'other' component, just to demonstrate getting and setting the service data.  However, it's just silently failing.

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your code is correct, it's just your `other` component do not know that you updated the service, so it will not request a new Data.
For this case Angular2 is using Observables :

**The Service :**

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
  // Observable string source
  private dataStringSource = new Subject<string>();

  // Observable string stream
  dataString$ = this.dataStringSource.asObservable();

  // Service message commands
  insertData(data: string) {
    this.dataStringSource.next(data)
  }
}
```

**The Main Component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [SharedService],
  directives: [OtherComponent],
  template: `
    <input type="text" #someValue>
    <button (click)="setSharedValue(someValue.value)">Change value in shared service</button>
    <br><br>
    <other></other>
  `
})
export class AppComponent { 
  constructor(private _sharedService: SharedService){}

  setSharedValue(value){ 
    this._sharedService.insertData(value);
  }
}
```

**The Other Component**

```
@Component({
  selector : "other",
  template : `
    I'm the other component. The shared data is: 
    <p>{{data}}</p>
  `,
})
export class OtherComponent implements OnInit{
  data: string;
  constructor(private _sharedService: SharedService){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this._sharedService.dataString$.subscribe(
      data => {
        this.data = data; 
      });
  }
}
```

The updated plunker can be found here : https://plnkr.co/edit/neM6EdYYUkGkRpF0fKGS?p=preview

Interaction between components in Angular2 can be found here : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: Nice answer. But what is the reason to use Observables instead of just having a public variable in the service which you can use to read/write? What are the benefits?

Comment: This is to create a listener in your component. So when you send the message from the Service the Component listen to that Observable and it will re-render and display the new value in the UI. If you create a simple public method in the Service then you can use the value, but you cannot listen to value change.

Answer (score 2):

I think  you are doing the right thing, just missing the last step which is to use Observables. I hope this [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37350935/how-do-i-bind-a-service-property-to-a-component-property-with-proper-change-trac/37355686#37355686) can help.

Answer (score 2):

Probably using observables is right thing to do but there is an alternative approach too.
Don't add `providers: [ SharedService ]` on any component, otherwise the components will get a different instance. Only provide it once at bootstrap().

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ SharedService ]);
```

then include this service in constructor of every component.

```
constructor(private _sharedService: SharedService){}
```

then you can set the value as :

```
this._sharedService.setSharedValue("your input");
```

and get the value as:

```
this.data = this._sharedService.dataString;
```

Comment: This still has the issue that the _other_ component will not notice if the service gets updated during runtime, so it will not receive the new data. Can someone confirm this?