# What is the best way for me to push data to a component from a service?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, service, observable

In my angular project I currently have a service that uses http calls to retrieve data from my java code. Every 10 seconds the service calls the Java side and gets new data from it. I now have another component that needs the data in my service. I need this component to have a field called 'data' that just gets updated automatically when the service gets new information.

**How can I set them up so that the service pushes the new information to my other component**? I would like to be able to use {{data}} in my component's html and have that be automatically updated without having to reload the page.

My component does have the service 'Autowired' in already. So currently I can just call 'this.data = this.service.getData()' but that call is within my ngOnInit method so it only happens once, and the data field does not get updated when the service's data field gets updated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I bind a service property to a component property with proper change tracking in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37350935/how-do-i-bind-a-service-property-to-a-component-property-with-proper-change-trac)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a messaging service that publishes data for subscribers or implement this functionality in your original service.

I would suggest having a separate messaging service and have relevant components or services publish/subscribe to it.

messaging.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';


@Injectable()
export class MessagingService {
  private sharedValue = new Subject<string>();  

  // Observable string streams
  sharedValue$ = this.sharedValue.asObservable();

    // Service message commands
  publishData(data: string) {
    this.sharedValue.next(data);
  }
```

You would inject the service like this:

```
constructor(private messagingService: MessagingService ) {}
```

Publish to the service:

```
this.messagingService.publishData(sharedValue);
```

Subscribe to the service:

```
this.messagingService.sharedValue$.subscribe(
            data => {                    
                this.localSharedValue = data;
            });
```

FROM ANSWER BELOW BY: DeborahK (who's courses on Pluralsight everyone should watch)

> Actually, all you need is a getter.
>
> Change your 'data' property to a getter and that will do the trick:
>
> ```
> get data(): any {
>     return this.service.getData();
> }
> ```
>
> Angular change detection will detect any time that data is changed in
>   the service which will cause it to re-evaluate its bindings and call
>   this getter to re-get the data.
>
> No need for a fancy service or Subject. :-)

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind but did not know how to execute it, thanks! So I am running into an interesting problem after using this. I am using this to get a list of clients from Java. When I use this method, it correctly retrieves the clients, and updates them if they change (woo!) however, when I grab the clients and set my field to be data, I try and call another method that uses the client list and within that method it is still undefined. It only works if i pass data into the method instead of using this.clients. Is there a way to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: @skyleguy Please post your code in a different question as it could be a lot of different things.  Without seeing the code it is hard to tell.  One possiblity is that your calling your method outside your subscribe() method.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, all you need is a getter.

Change your 'data' property to a getter and that will do the trick:

```
get data(): any {
    return this.service.getData();
}
```

Angular change detection will detect any time that data is changed in the service which will cause it to re-evaluate its bindings and call this getter to re-get the data.

No need for a fancy service or `Subject`. :-)

Comment: I believe that is what I tried to do first and it did not work... I must not have done something correctly. I will definitely try this the next time this issue comes up because it is definitely more simple and less time consuming. Gonna have to give change detection a read as well. Thanks!

Comment: @DeborahK I love your courses.  One down side with this approach is that it is 'auto-magical'  there is nothing explicit about how the data is being pushed or updated.  It is true that this is an great and time saving feature, but I am always hesitate to add code that isn't explicit about what it is doing.

Comment: Thanks! And as they say: "Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic" LOL. Do you use data binding? Getters use the same "magical" approach as data binding. All you are doing with a getter vs a property declaration is allowing it to get the latest version of the value each time.

Comment: Data bindings are doing it explicitly (ie most developers expect them to bind).  A getter is an accessor method, which returns the value of a private member variable (most developers won't assume that it is going push/update data). I have to admit that most of my knowledge of Angular comes from your courses so I am a little out of my league in this discussion :)

Comment: No, the getters don't push/update the data. They are *simply* property declarations with some code in them. They don't do anything special. When Angular's change detection detects something has changed, it rebinds and gets the current property value. All we are adding is the ability to call some other code (a property in our service) when the binding occurs. There is no magic here. The current course I'm working on goes through this in detail. It's called "Angular Component Communication".